# Button click inside update panel causes all page disabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a button inside update panel this button fill a grid view inside the same update panel when click on this button all page controls is disabled and i can't do any action on this page.
I tried to make update panel update mode to conditional but the same occurs.
page works only when clear all update panels from this page?
`

### Xyz

```
                                <div id="Div18" >
                                    <asp:GridView ID="gvinnertranssides" runat="server" BackColor="White"
                                        BorderColor="#999999" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3"
                                        ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Height="16px" Width="100%" CssClass="Grid"
                                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" OnRowCommand="gvinnertranssides_ItemCommand" OnPageIndexChanging="gvinnertranssides_PageIndexChanging" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10">
                                        <Columns>
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="x" HeaderText="x" SortExpression="x" Visible="true" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Y" HeaderText="Y" SortExpression="Y" Visible="true" />

                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="Serial" HeaderText="Serial" SortExpression="Serial" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SideName" HeaderText="SideName" SortExpression="SideName" />
                                            <asp:BoundField DataField="SectionName" HeaderText="القسم" SortExpression="SectionName" />
                                        </Columns>
                                    </asp:GridView>


                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                                </ContentTemplate>
                        </asp:updatepanel>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I can't comment on question reputation is less then 50.

Please provide your code of update panel and datagrid.
I have the following UpdatePanel and it is working perfect for me.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSearch" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                    <ContentTemplate>
                                        <asp:Panel ID="Panel2" runat="server" Width="100%" Height="500px" 
                                            ScrollBars="Auto" ondatabinding="Page_Load">

                                            <asp:DataGrid ID="grdacwReport" runat="server" CssClass="GridViewStyle" 
                                                Width="100%" ondatabinding="Page_Load"

                                                PageSize="100" >

                                                <FooterStyle CssClass="GridViewFooterStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                                    VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                                                <ItemStyle CssClass="GridViewRowStyle" />
                                                <PagerStyle CssClass="GridViewPagerStyle" HorizontalAlign="Center" 
                                                    NextPageText=">>" PageButtonCount="100" PrevPageText="<<" 
                                                    VerticalAlign="Bottom" />
                                                <AlternatingItemStyle CssClass="GridViewAlternatingRowStyle" />
                                                <HeaderStyle CssClass="GridViewHeaderStyle" />

                                            </asp:DataGrid>

                                        </asp:Panel>
                                    </ContentTemplate>
                                </asp:UpdatePanel>
```